# PHP autenticação OAuth2

Tags: php, restful

Estou fazendo um web service Restful, o OAuth é a melhor forma de autenticar e trabalhar com token?

É possível usar o OAuth2 para autenticar via usuário e senha?

Answer (score 2):

Autorização por meio do protocolo OAuth é a principal forma de autorização que utilizo nas minhas aplicações. Por meio dele é possível que os *clientes* obtenham acesso aos *recursos da aplicação* usando tokens de acesso, que podem ser obtidos fornecendo-se um nome de usuário e senha, ou um token de atualização.

Logo, é possível obter um token de acesso usando um nome de usuário e senha – confira a seção 1.3.3 do RFC 6749, que trata especificamente desse tipo de acesso:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3

O que eu faço é o seguinte:

- Se o usuário não possuir nenhum token de acesso, ele fornece os nomes de usuário e senha para a aplicação, que por meio de um *servidor de autorização*, obtém um par de credenciais que são um token de acesso (*access token*) e um token de atualização (*refresh token*);
- As obtenções seguintes de um novo par de token de acesso + token de atualização pode ser obtido fornecendo-se o token de atualização anterior, e assim sucessivamente;
- Dessa forma o usuário não precisa fornecer seu nome de usuário e senha sempre que seu token de acesso expira: basta, de forma invisível para ele, trocar o token de atualização por um novo token de acesso.

Comment: Certo, a tabela de clients eu não consegui entender, pelo que entendi eu registro um client lá tipo client web, mobile ?

Comment: É isso mesmo. A vantagem de se usar clientes para intermediar a obtenção de tokens de acesso é que você pode criar vários – um para cada necessidade, ou revogar um (ou mais) deles. Veja essa seção do RFC, que trata especificamente do registro dos clientes de acesso: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2